# Upload multiple images within single upload button Django-rest framework without forms

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I understand this is an old question but I didn't get a proper answer for this. I have seen answers which use multiple upload buttons and calling them multiple uploading, well what I'm asking is, how to upload images like more than 1000 with a single upload button? It would be really helpful if anyone can answer or suggest any links related to this. Thank you!

> I'm asking with **Django rest framework without forms.** Because I will be using **react as frontend**.